# How to save first item in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, remote-access

Below is my script:

```
from __future__ import print_function

# import statements
import sys, subprocess
import wmi, win32api, win32con


# get the arguments and extract user's IP address
argument = sys.argv[1]
attr_map = dict(item.strip().split('=') for item in argument.split(','))
userIP =  attr_map['sender-ip']
print (userIP)


# subprocess
ping = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ping", "-n", "1", userIP],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
)



# can we ping the user's IP address?
out, error = ping.communicate()

# if we cannot ping user's IP address then print error message and exit program
if out.find("Reply from") == -1:
    print (userIP, "is NOT pingable.")
    sys.exit()


# try to access wmi
try:
    c = wmi.WMI(userIP)
except: 
    print ("Cannot access WMI for", userIP)
    sys.exit()


for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print (os.Caption)

# perform system lookup of IP address

for us in c.Win32_LogonSession():
    try:
        for user in us.references("Win32_LoggedOnUser"):
            print(user.Antecedent.Domain, user.Antecedent.Name, sep="\\")
    except:
        pass
```

But it outputs multiple users.

```
DOMAIN\Glowie
DOMAIN\service_account
DOMAIN\service_account
DOMAIN\service_account
DOMAIN\service_account
```

How to get first user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a tuple or array, you can use the brackets to access an element:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x[0]
1
```